# Why the inout port value is not being updated by last assign statement?

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

Why the last `assign` statement is not updating the value `temp_sum` to `sum`? In simulator it is showing `temp_sum` value as 30, but that 30 is not being updated to `sum`. Note that `sum` here is used as `inout`.

```
module adder(input [63:0] in, inout [63:0] sum);

// Declare a wire variable to hold the sum    
wire [63:0] temp_sum;

// Add the input to the sum         
assign temp_sum = sum + in;

// Assign the sum output using a continuous assignment    
assign sum = temp_sum;

endmodule
```

I want updated verilog code

Answer (score 0):

That is a misuse of an `inout` port.  They are tricky to use, and require more code to control when they are being used as an input vs. when they are used as an output.

It is much more common to add 2 input ports together into one output port:

```
module adder (input [63:0] in1, in2, output [63:0] sum);
    assign sum = in1 + in2;
endmodule
```

You probably want to use a carry bit as well.

Answer (score 0):

In the scheme like you have you just created a zero-delay loop. This will potentially  cause simulation to hang if any value changes.

temp_sum -> updates sum -> increments temp_sum -> updates sum -> upd...

It will be stable in two cases:

1. if it was not initialize and all values are 'x', any operation in this module will return 'x'
2. if values are initialized and 'in' is 0.

In all other cases it will not work.

You need to add a flop to resolve it.